# Unwanted divider between header and table in Android

Tags: java, android, user-interface, tablelayout

I am developing an Android app and I created a TableLayout to display some information, but the table I created has a grey divider between the table header and the rest of the rows that **gets bigger the more records there are on the table**.

[This is how the table looks with 20~ rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/38sEU.png)

I just created a TableLayout inside of some other containers like so:

```xml
FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".fragmentos.TablaAsig">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <HorizontalScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TableLayout
                        android:id="@+id/tablaSinAsig"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
                        android:divider="?android:listDivider"
                        android:paddingBottom="60dp"
                        android:showDividers="middle">

                        <!-- Header de la tabla -->

                        <TableRow
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                            android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
                            android:padding="10dp">


                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                                android:text="Asignatu gabeko TAG-ak" />
                        </TableRow>
                    </TableLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </HorizontalScrollView>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</FrameLayout>
```

And I have a function that creates new TableRows to insert into this TableLayout:

```
public void poblarTablaSinAsig(Context context, TableLayout tableLayout){
        tagsSinAsig = new ArrayList<String>();
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        int filas = tableLayout.getChildCount();
        for (int i = 1; i < filas; i++) {
            View child = tableLayout.getChildAt(i);
            if (child instanceof TableRow) ((ViewGroup) child).removeAllViews();
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < EventHandler.allTagData.size(); i++) {
            TableRow nuevoReg = new TableRow(context);
            TextView codTag = new TextView(context);

            TableRow.LayoutParams parametros = new TableRow.LayoutParams(
                    TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
            );

            parametros.setMargins(50, 15, 10, 15);
            nuevoReg.setLayoutParams(parametros);


            Cursor cursor = null;
            String query = "SELECT * FROM asignaciones WHERE CodigoChip = '" +  EventHandler.allTagData.get(i) + "'";
            cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

            if(cursor.getCount() <= 0) {
                codTag.setText(EventHandler.allTagData.get(i));
                nuevoReg.addView(codTag, parametros);
                tableLayout.addView(nuevoReg, parametros);
                tagsSinAsig.add(EventHandler.allTagData.get(i));
            } else {
                tagsAsig.add(EventHandler.allTagData.get(i));
                }
            }
    }
```

Where is this weird divider being created? How can I solve the problem?